# How search for dll and functions in stack of process in process monitor?

Tags: process, sysinternals, process-monitor

I am using process monitor to track a process. ( I don't know if there is a better tool like that).

Is there a way to **search** or **filter** for where exactly I have a specific dll say myName.dll with a specific function DoWork loaded in stack?

The manual way is by double clicking each process and checking stack after symbols are loaded.

Any quick way to do that?

thanks

Comment: I think you have to export the captured data to XML and check the stack info..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name of the DLL, you can monitor a process and find when a specific DLL is loaded.

If you are looking to log calls to a loaded DLL's function, you can use [WinAPIOverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/).